# Can every algorithm be represented by a finite state machine?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, state-machine

I understand that it's possible to represent some algorithms as FSMs, but can FSMs describe every possible algorithm?

Comment: you could also think about the question as: would there be a use for thinking about Turing machines if they are only as powerful as FSMs? But since we *are* talking about Turing machines, there must be things they can do (algorithms) but FSMs can't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Intuitively, an algorithm can only be represented as an FSM if it uses only a finite amount of state. For instance, you couldn't sort an arbitrary-length list with an FSM.

Now, add an unbounded amount of state to an FSM -- like an infinite one-dimensional array of values... and add a little bit of "glue" state between the FSM and the array -- a notion of "current position" in that array... and you've got a Turing machine. Which, yes, can do it all.

Comment: Might be worth discussing that while you can't sort an arbitrary-length list with an FSM; for any given length of list, you could construct an FSM that could sort it. A PC is an FSM after all - just that all that RAM and disk gives it a *vast* number of states.

Comment: @slim I really dislike the claim "the PC is an FSM", everything could be a FSM in real life, sicne there is a finite number of atoms in the universe, but honestly - a PC can expand its memory during runtime (using a constantly expanding cluster, adding more memory devices,...), and is realisitcally not an FSM.

Answer (score 7):

No.

There is a finite state machine that can describe every Regular Language.
For irregular languages, Finite State Machines, are not enough.

The set of all programs, are called the "Recursively enumerable" languages, and can be accepted by a Turing Machine.

This is often referred as the [**Chomsky Hirerchy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy):

```
Regular Languages <= Context Free Languages <= Context Sensitive Languages <= Recursively enumerable Languages
```

Which are accepted by:

1. Regular languages: Finite State Machine
2. Context Free Language: Push-down automaton
3. Context Sensitive Languages: Linear Bounded Turing Machines
4. Recursively enumerable Languages: Turing Machines

It is important to note that a machine that can accepted describe all "higher tier languages" can also describe all the lower tiers (for example, you can create a turing machine to accept each regular language)